# Merging Duplicate cells in SLDS table on multiple columns

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, lightning-datatable, table

I am stuck while trying to create logic for merging duplicate cells coming from apex call on load. It is a simple SOQL on sobject.

I understand from my research on internet that rowspan is to be used in order to achieve merge on the  tag so i modified my apex return type in my LWC js and my final Array on which I iterate looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Level1_Type_Eng__c": "Sales",
    "Level2_Type_Eng__c": "Business Preparation",
    "Type_Eng__c": "Customer Relationship",
    "Id": "a1hN0000001w877IAA",
    "firstSpanLength": 8,
    "secondLevelCombinedData": [
      "Business Preparation",
      "Business Preparation",
      "Business Preparation",
      "Industry Competency",
      "Industry Competency",
      "Industry Competency",
      "Price",
      "Price"
    ],
    "thirdLevelCombinedData": [
      "Customer Relationship",
      "Response to Requirement",
      "Sales Strategy",
      "Business (Partner/Consortium)",
      "Prior Business (ISP/MP)",
      "Customer Trust (Awareness, etc.)",
      "Bid Price",
      "Free Support"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Level1_Type_Eng__c": "Own Product",
    "Level2_Type_Eng__c": "Product Structure",
    "Type_Eng__c": "Customer Preference",
    "Id": "a1hN0000001w87qIAA",
    "firstSpanLength": 4,
    "secondLevelCombinedData": [
      "Product Structure",
      "Product Structure",
      "Technic",
      "Technic"
    ],
    "thirdLevelCombinedData": [
      "Customer Preference",
      "Readiness",
      "Coverage",
      "Skill Level"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Level1_Type_Eng__c": "Execution",
    "Level2_Type_Eng__c": "Proposal",
    "Type_Eng__c": "Proposal Strategy",
    "Id": "a1hN0000001w885IAA",
    "firstSpanLength": 4,
    "secondLevelCombinedData": [
      "Proposal",
      "Proposal",
      "Execution Ready",
      "Execution Ready"
    ],
    "thirdLevelCombinedData": [
      "Proposal Strategy",
      "Response to Customer Requirement",
      "PM/Manpower/Partner",
      "Biz Experience/Competency"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Level1_Type_Eng__c": "Etc",
    "Level2_Type_Eng__c": "Etc",
    "Type_Eng__c": "Etc",
    "Id": "a1hN0000001w88PIAQ",
    "firstSpanLength": 1,
    "secondLevelCombinedData": [
      "Etc"
    ],
    "thirdLevelCombinedData": [
      "Etc"
    ]
  }
]
```

It contains 4 entries as shown above. For comparison the JSON from the working blog is below:

```
[
  {
    "family": "Family 1",
    "products": [
      {
        "family": "Family 1",
        "assetName": "Name 1",
        "assetType": "Type 1"
      },
      {
        "family": "Family 1",
        "assetName": "Name 2",
        "assetType": "Type 2"
      },
      {
        "family": "Family 1",
        "assetName": "Name 3",
        "assetType": "Type 3"
      }
    ],
    "rowspan": 4
  },
  {
    "family": "Family 2",
    "products": [
      {
        "family": "Family 2",
        "assetName": "Name 4",
        "assetType": "Type 4"
      },
      {
        "family": "Family 2",
        "assetName": "Name 5",
        "assetType": "Type 5"
      }
    ],
    "rowspan": 3
  },
  {
    "family": "Family 3",
    "products": [
      {
        "family": "Family 3",
        "assetName": "Name 6",
        "assetType": "Type 6"
      }
    ],
    "rowspan": 2
  }
]
```

"Level1_Type_Eng__c" would be the data for my first column and firstSpanLength defines the rowspan for these values. (I am yet to do calculation of rowspan for 2nd and 3rd column but that is fairly simple.

i thought it would work fine but I am seeing very weird results. I am not sure if my understanding of using html tables   tags is correct.

The code on html side is exact like this from [this](https://www.forcetrails.com/2019/11/how-to-create-slds-table-with-cell.html) blog




{family.family}





{product.assetName}


{product.assetType}

This blog one works fine but mine is somehow broken. the backend logic is not at all same from this blog to my logic in JS but I believe the end Iterable structure is identical so not sure what is wrong with my html display. here is the screenshot of my screen the above table is from blog which works fine below table is mine.

My first column only need to have Level1_Type_Eng__c data with rowspan as "firstSpanLength" and second coolumn should be "secondLevelCombinedData" and third column should be "thirdLevelCombinedData" everything is populated but table does not populate fine. Please help me understand what i am missing. what i think is that my understanding on how to iterte over it in html and td and tr tags is messing thing up. Any help here is appreciated.

If from the above "first" JSON can anyone suggest best approach to show duplicate data as merged cells in LWC HTML that would also be of great help because at this point i am stuck since many hours. Screenshot from my screen for referece:

[image]

Thank you.

Edit:

Picture of Excel represantation of actual data:
[image]
From the above picture what I want if you see in column "Level1_Type_Eng__c" the entry "Sales" is coming 8 times so the requirement is to remove duplicacy here and only show "Sales" one time instead of 8 times (for this i believe rowspan=8 is to be given) in the similar way i need to remove duplicate entry like the image below(this should be the final result)
[image]

Comment: From our findings `colspan` works in grids, but `rowspan` only works for tables.

Comment: Can you [edit] to add how you are rendering the data? And please provide an example of what you have with the basic data and what you want to achieve with the "duplicate" removal? (As visual representations, perhaps done in excel manually?)

Comment: Hello @PhilW I have added screenshot by editing my description can you check if that helps in better understanding of the requirement. I am working with rowspans here. code of which is already mentioned . thank you.

Comment: @PhilW I have now added the visual representation of how i want the end result as well you may refer to it also.

HTML code is added.
Array JSON is also provided above 

please let me know if I can provide you with any other information regarding it.

Thank you for your response.